# Powershell Uploading complete folder hierarchy to document Library

Tags: 2013, powershell, file-upload, script

I have the below script that currently only uploads the content of a single folder. However I have ~300 folders to upload and changing the folder name each time before running the script is not very practical. Is there a way to upload the documents (with or with out the folders)?

---

Current Script:

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}



$webUrl = "WEBSITE URL"

$docLibraryName = "Documents"

$docLibraryUrlName = "Shared%20Documents"

$localFolderPath = "C:\PARENT\CHILD FOLDER\"


$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl

$docLibrary = $web.Lists[$docLibraryName]

$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item $localFolderPath)).GetFiles()

ForEach($file in $files)
{

    #Open file
    $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()

    #Add file
    $folder =  $web.getfolder($docLibraryUrlName)

    write-host "Copying file " $file.Name " to " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl "..."
    $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
    write-host "Success"

    #Close file stream
    $fileStream.Close();
}

$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Do you want to create folder as well in to document library?

Comment: Ideally it wouldn't have folders so the script you provided works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below script will upload file recursively from folder to document library

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
     Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

Function UploadFiles($web,$path,$docLibrary)
{
$files = Get-ChildItem $path

foreach ($file in $files) 
{  

   if($file.GetType().Name -eq "DirectoryInfo") 
   {
        #Item Is Folder
        Write-Host  $file.FullName
        Write-Host "Calling inner function"
        UploadFiles $web $file.FullName $docLibrary
   }
   else
   {
        #Item is File
        Write-Host  $file.FullName
         #Open file
        $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()

        #Add file
        $folder =  $web.getfolder($docLibraryUrlName)

        write-host "Copying file " $file.Name " to " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl "..."
        $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
        write-host "Success"

        #Close file stream
        $fileStream.Close();
   }

}
}
$webUrl = "WEBSITE URL"
$docLibraryName = "Documents"
$docLibraryUrlName = "Shared%20Documents"
$localFolderPath = "C:\FolderWhichContainsAllFilesWithSubFolder\"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$docLibrary = $web.Lists[$docLibraryName]
UploadFiles $web $localFolderPath $docLibrary
$web.Dispose()
```

Hope it will help to you.

Comment: Sorry for late comment (Had sort out other back end stuff so the server could talk to each other)

When I run this script it doesn't execute.
it goes into a >> mode where I can continue writing after doing a copy paste into it (after putting in my server details, etc).

How do you get out of the >> so the code can run?

Comment: Moved the following lines above the function call. Works fine now.

$webUrl = "WEBSITE URL"
$docLibraryName = "Documents"
$docLibraryUrlName = "Shared%20Documents"
$localFolderPath = "C:\FolderWhichContainsAllFilesWithSubFolder\"

Comment: Ok.. good. :):)