# Powershell script to transfer folders from local folder to document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am new to Sharepoint and would like to write a PowerShell script to transfer folders from a local folder to a document library (Sharepoint 2016).

May I know if it's possible, and the way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, only files are supported to be uploaded using PowerShell but folders are not. To upload files in a local folder to SharePoint library, see this: [Powershell Uploading complete folder hierarchy to document Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/147432/powershell-uploading-complete-folder-hierarchy-to-document-library). Alternatively, some 3rd party migration tools may support moving folders from local to SharePoint library.

Comment: Nice, thanks, Allen_MSFT.
This one goes into the folder and uploads the folder's files individually onto SharePoint Library..
I wonder if there is a way to recreate the folder if we can upload the folder to SharePoint via Powershell.. Will try it out.